# Can we commit Shirk or Kufr while playing and doing actions in videogames?

Tags: shirk, kufr, sihr

As Salam Alaykum brothers

I wanted to know if playing games that contain knowledge of magic like The Witcher 3, or consulting an oracle in Assassins Creed Odyssey, does this entail shirk or kufr? Even if my intention is not to do these sins and i dont believe even a little bit in these acts, just doing it to advance in the game

For example, im pretty sure that killing in a game is not considered killing in real world, but knowledge of magic and consulting an oracle, i think there is more depth on the subject

Answer (score 1):

Brother, Allah granted you the gift of life for a preciously short amount of time on this earth.  Not only that, each day that you wake up, remember that Allah returned your soul to your body to give you another day to repent, and use your day to make salah, donate zakah, make dawah, and struggle for the sake of Allah (fee sabeel ilah).  You need to appreciate each precious moment that Allah has gifted you and use this time in Allah's cause.  There is really no such thing as "free time".  If Allah has given you "extra" time that is not needed (a gift most of humanity is not getting) for supporting yourself and your family, it is up to you spend this extra time in a manner most pleasing to Allah.

Your decision to spend this time to participate in video game entertainment, even if the games are sanitized of shameful, idolatrous, or degrading content, shows where your priorities for using your time are.  On Yawmi Deen (day of judgement) you will be questioned about this use of time. Instead of spending your time participating in fantasy video game entertainment, you can spend your time to warn those who have fallen into sheydan's trap against squandering their precious time in idle or makruh activities.

So, to answer your question: participating in video game entertainment, even with sanitized content, while maybe not really commiting shirk, is sinful in the sense of squandering your precious time in idle activities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get involved in shirk/kufr while playing video games. I never played PUBG, Alhamdulillah, but it has a act of shirk in it. In my country where im from there was a push from Islamic Scholars to get anyone who did it to touba from it and renew their faith. You wont understand what they are saying in the following video but they were basically saying whoever did this act of shirk is non-muslim now and they need to touba and renew their faith(and renew their marriage if they were married). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw0_Qs8C6VQ

Comment: Can you explain on what fiqh (4 traditional Sunni, Salafiya or Shia sect) and what exactly is declared shirk (most readers do not know the game, for good reasons)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu Alaikum

Magic and Worshipping of false idols is Shirk. But you already know it and you are aware that the stuff in the game isn’t real and the stuff in real life isn’t a game. You wouldn’t be traveling around trying to find things with the Witcher’s magic in real life? And you can’t play the game (very well) while avoiding digital magic in the game.

The bottom line is if you know the difference and you believe that they are not the same. It’s not Shirk! However you should skip scenes which displays nudity, sex and other vulgar things because that is still haram (even if it’s a manga cartoon).